# C++ Sort and Binary Search with arrays issue

Tags: c++, sorting

I am a beginner programmer and am having an issue with getting this problem solved. The assignment is asking to use this method (greaterAlpha()) but I am not entirely sure what the purpose is. Can someone help me get this working and explain what this method is being used for?

I am supposed to fix the previous assignment to read from the file and out print the name and number with dots. **The add-on is the sort function which is supposed to sort the last name in alphabetical order using the greaterAlpha() method. After all of that, it is supposed to loop through using a key to do a binary search using the same greaterAlpha() method. (The binary search is used in the sort for its comparisons, and must return the subscript of the element if found, the negative of the subscript of the last tested element if not.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
//*********************************************************************
class PhoneNumber
{
    private:
        int areaCode,
            prefix,
            lineNumber;
    public:                              // the methods are public
    void setNumber(int area, int pre, int num)
    {
        areaCode = area;
        prefix = pre;
        lineNumber = num;
    }
    int getAreaCode() const
    {
        return areaCode;
    }
    int getPrefix() const
    {
        return prefix;
    }
    int getLineNumber() const
    {
        return lineNumber;
    }
    istream& readPhone(istream&);         // input/output functions
    ostream& printPhone(ostream&) const;
};
//*********************************************************************
// Returns istream& so it can be used to overload the >> operator later
istream& PhoneNumber::readPhone(istream& fin)
{
    return fin >> areaCode >> prefix >> lineNumber;
}
//*********************************************************************
// Returns ostream& so it can be used to overload the << opeator later
ostream& PhoneNumber::printPhone(ostream& fout) const
{
    fout << setw(4) << areaCode << "-" << prefix << "-" << lineNumber;
    return fout;
}
//*********************************************************************
class PhoneEntry
{
    private:
        string  lastName,
                firstName;
        PhoneNumber Number;
    public:
        void setNames(string last, string first)
        {
            lastName = last;
            firstName= first;
        }
        string getLastName() 
        {
            return lastName;
        }
        string getFirstName()
        {
            return firstName;
        }
        istream& readEntry(istream&);
        ostream& writeDots(ostream&, int);
        ostream& printEntry(ostream&);
        bool greaterAlpha(PhoneEntry&) const;
        void selectionSort(string, int);
};
//*********************************************************************
istream& PhoneEntry::readEntry(istream& fin)
{
    fin >> lastName >> firstName;
    Number.readPhone(fin);
    return fin;
}
//*********************************************************************
ostream& PhoneEntry::writeDots(ostream& fout, int length) 
{
    length = firstName.length();
    length += lastName.length();
    length += 2;
    //This line is causing the issue but WHY?

    if(length % 2 == 1)
    {
        fout << ".";
    }

    for(length; length <= 28; length++)
    {
        fout << " .";
        length++;
    }

    return fout;
}
//*********************************************************************
ostream& PhoneEntry::printEntry(ostream& fout) 
{
    int length = 0;

    fout << lastName << ", " << firstName;
    writeDots(fout, length);
    Number.printPhone(fout);

    return fout;
}
//*********************************************************************
bool PhoneEntry::greaterAlpha (PhoneEntry& x) const 
{
    bool flag;

    if (lastName > x.lastName)
        flag = true;
    else if ((lastName == x.lastName) && (firstName > x.firstName))
        flag = true;
    else 
        flag = false;

    return flag;
}
//*********************************************************************
void selectionSort(string name[], int elems) 
{ 
    int startScan, minIndex; 
    string strName; 
    for (startScan = 0; startScan < (elems - 1); startScan++) 
    { 
        minIndex = startScan; 
        strName = name[startScan]; 
        for(int index = startScan + 1; index < elems; index++) 
        { 
            if (name[index] < strName) 
            { 
                strName = name[index]; 
                minIndex = index; 
            } 
        } 
        name[minIndex] = name[startScan]; 
        name[startScan] = strName; 
    } 
} 
//*********************************************************************
int main()
{
   int count;
    const int MAX_CAPACITY = 500;
    PhoneEntry Entry[MAX_CAPACITY],
               EntryIn;
    bool flag = false;

    ifstream dataIn("phonenum.txt");

    if(!dataIn)
    {
        perror("phonenum.txt");
        exit(1);
    }

    count = 0;
    while (count < MAX_CAPACITY && EntryIn.readEntry(dataIn)) 
    {
        Entry[count++] = EntryIn;
    }

    dataIn.close();

    if (count == MAX_CAPACITY)
    {
        cerr << "Reached maximum capacity of " << MAX_CAPACITY << ", can't read anymore Phone Entries currently." << endl;
    }

    //EntryIn.greaterAlpha(Entry);
    selectionSort(Entry, count);

    if (flag) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            Entry[i].printEntry(cout) << endl;
        }
    }
    else 
        cerr << "Error with sort!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I know this is coded terribly but that is how the instructor is wanting this to be written. Any assistance or constructive criticism would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: Quite a lot of code for a question... have you tried to narrow it down?

Comment: Use a very small dataset (i.e. only a couple of data entries) and step through the code in a debugger. It will help you narrow down where the problem may be.

Comment: I'm not clear what the question is.

Comment: I keep getting errors on the errors on the selectionSort() method. Following what the person did below, I get an error on the method itself, stating declartion is incompatible with "void PhoneEntry::selctionSort(PhoneEntry *, int). I have the main part of the program working, just the selection sort isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just asking what the `greaterAlpha` method is for?

If so, you should use it for comparing two `PhoneEntry` instances where you used to use `<` for sorting and searching, i.e.

```
void selectionSort(PhoneEntry[] entries, int elems) 
{
// ...
            PhoneEntry entry = entries[startScan];
// ... 
            if (entry.greaterAlpha(entries[index]))
//...  
}
```

The binary search is also a very simple change if you've already got it implemented with `std::string`s.

Side note: many would prefer to condense the comparison method to

```
bool PhoneEntry::greaterAlpha (PhoneEntry& x) const 
{
    return  lastName > x.lastName
        || (lastName == x.lastName && firstName > x.firstName);
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error on the selectionSort() method of "entries" array. It doesn't like the entries in the method header and it also says that entries and elems is undefined. Why would that be?